# Javascript Image slide show loop

Tags: javascript, html, image, slideshow

I have the code for the slideshow. 
However what I'm wanting to do is on load an input box for a user to input the name of a folder then the page to locate that folder and show each image from that folder. **I've managed to do this by having two different pages, one with an input box then the other showing the images.**

However I'd rather not hard code the image source as I want the webpage to run on a server but different slide shows might be run in different places in the company. From the research I've done I think I need a for loop, to loop round each picture in the folder but not 100% sure. This is what I've got so far:

I've passed in the folder name from the previous page. But as you can see the image paths are still hard coded in. I would like a for loop to loop through each picture and show them all on the webpage, no matter where they are/how many there are as long as they inputted the correct folder/Slideshow name. As the image folder will all be in the same place on the network path.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var first = getUrlVars()["SlideShowTest"];

function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
        vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
}
//alert(first)
//-->
</script>


</head>
<body>


<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var step=1
function slideit(){
document.images.slide.src=eval("image"+step+".src")
if(step<3)
step++
else
step=1
setTimeout("slideit()",2500)
}
slideit()
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it might work.

Regarding style, you could put the Images into an array to get rid of the eval:

```
var images= [];
var image;
image= new Image();
image.src= '...';
images.push(image);

for(var i=0; i<images.length; ++i) { 
   image= images[i];
   ...
}
```

It also is better to use setInterval("slideit()",2500); once instead of setTimeout.

Comment: So how would I say for every image within the folder? Do (the slide show)